# Is ArcGIS API for JavaScript compatible with Internet Explorer 7 and 8?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, internet-explorer

I've developed a web map using ArcGIS API for JavaScrip version 3.8 and its not compatible with IE 7 or 8. I've advised the people who have reported this to update their version of IE but, if it doesn't involve rewriting the website, I'd like to offer something that can work with these versions.

Here's the website: http://il.water.usgs.gov/data/mchenry/map.php

As you can see, in IE 7 or 8 the map doesn't even load which throws javascript errors.

*EDIT*

I have added some script that changes the markup and css to handle HTML in IE versions lower than 9 found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449502/html5-and-css3-for-ie7-and-ie8

Since doing this, I've noticed that the map loads on zoom in/out but none of my points load.

Comment: According to https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/supported_browsers.html they should be supported.

Comment: Uh oh, that's even stranger then! Does it work for you on the old IE document settings? I couldn't get the map to load.

Comment: According to validator.w3.org there are 136 errors in your document. Most of them are on line 63, which is nearly 20,000 characters long.

Comment: @Mintx do you these errors could cause the map to not load at all? Maybe IE7 and IE8 can't handle HTML5?

Comment: IE7 and IE8 cannot handle HTML5 without some additional JS libraries. You can try adding html5shiv: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: @Mintx if you look at my edit, I added this which fixed some of it, but the map still doesn't load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @blah238 both Internet Explorer versions of 7 and 8 should be supported by the ArcGIS API for JavaScript because the [list of supported browsers](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/supported_browsers.html) includes:

> - Internet Explorer 7+

From the comments it appears that the source of problems must be something other than just the Internet Explorer version being used.

To progress this further you could contact support.esri.com or ask a new question that becomes more focussed than this one by zero-ing in on any learnings that have come from the comments and since that time.